# Using dbplyr for multiple database merging

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbplyr

My database engine in SQL server consists of 2 databases. I'd like to have some joint tables from two different databases but so far I couldn't.

Here is how I tried;

```
library(odbc)
library(dbplyr)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),driver='SQL Server',server = 'myserver',database='db1',encoding='windows-1254')

table1 <- tbl(con,in_schema('db1.dbo','abc'))

table2 <- tbl(con,in_schema('db2.dbo','cde'))
```

as such, it raises an error ;

```
[SQL Server]Invalid object name 'db1.dbo.abc'.  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

but this looking table links works fine;

```
table1 <- tbl(con,in_schema('dbo','abc'))
```

it works because I already specified database in the connection object but now I want to use a table with same connection but from another database. I cannot declare a new connection, when I do this, it copies tables which is to be joint to my local and it takes too long.

I shouldn't write an native SQL query instead of `dbplyr` and use one connection object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hi , I thought that but my user doesn't have permission to `CREATE SYNONYM`

Comment: @AaronBertrand probably our system admin, I can only run queries

Comment: what is the problem with `t1 = tbl(con, in_schema('dbo','abc'))` and `t2 = tbl(con,in_schema('db2.dbo','cde'))`?   Then something like `inner_join(t1,t2, by=...)`??

Comment: @langtang I'm getting the same error while creating `t2`

Comment: sorry, see my answer below. You should use `dplyr::sql()` to wrap the schema and table values when using `con` to reach db2.  Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able wrap the schema value and table value in `dplyr::sql()` when trying to use `con` for `db1` to reach `db2`

```
table1 <- tbl(con,in_schema('dbo','abc'))
table2 <- tbl(con,in_schema(dplyr::sql('db2.dbo'),dplyr::sql('cde')))
```